# Database backup not working using database manager

Tags: postgresql, odoo

I'd like to backup a db today through localhost:8069/web/database/manager
, but the button return nothing while clicking the button.
Terminal show no error there.
Also invalid for duplicate, delete, create database,restore database and set Master password except link of existed db.

see pic as below: [image]

the problem emerged since I deployed odoo12.

I can directly backup through pgAdmin4.
but I still want to know what happened.

My version of pgsql is 9.6 for odoo10 and odoo11.
It worked smoothly before I deployed odoo12

Comment: Does your browser has any JavaScript-blocking extension?

Comment: I found the reason. thx for reply.

Answer (score 3):

I found it's a stupid question.

the reason is that I connect to wrong db_host:
my conf set db_host as 127.0.0.1 but connect to localhost.

[image]

keep this topic for who make same mistake